# Best practice for using input data from external file in different functions

Tags: c++, class, global-variables

For a small project in c++ I need to initialize a number of variables from a text file and make these available for several functions in the code. The way I do it at the moment is to create a class that reads and returns those values and make a single global instance of the class that is then accessible by all functions in the project. However, to me this seems not a very elegant solution and I am wondering what would be the best practice here. Parsing the variables as arguments is not really an option for me as I typically need many these variables in the different functions.

Thanks for any suggestions!

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class indata {
    int age;
    double weight;
    double length;
public:
    indata ();
    int getAge(void)
    {
        return age;
    }
    double getWeight(void)
    {
        return weight;
    }
    double getLength(void)
    {
        return length;
    }
};

indata::indata () {
    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open ("input.dat");
    inputfile>>age;
    inputfile>>weight;
    inputfile>>length;
    inputfile.close();
};

// make class instance global
indata in;

double Length2inch()
{
    const double cm2inch = 1./2.54;
    double Length = in.getLength();
    return Length*cm2inch;
};

int main () {
    cout << "Age    :  " << in.getAge() << endl;
    cout << "Weight :  " << in.getWeight() << endl;
    cout << "Length :  " << in.getLength() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Length in inches: " << Length2inch() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

input.dat:

```
32
75
175
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the class object around?

Comment: that sounds simple enough :) Thanks